# Math formula python interpretation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to convert this math formula into python.

[image]

So basically the approximation of 1/math.pi.

I tried making this iteration with

```
import math

N = 132
for k in range(1, N+1):
    print("The N value is",N , end="\r", flush=True)

rec_pi_approximate = (2*math.sqrt(2)/9801) * N * ((math.factorial(4*k) * (1103+26390*k))/((math.factorial(k)**4) * (396**4*k)))
```

But my values have been weird and I need guidance on how to actually type the formula and make a summation loop for it. Currently I am trying to find the reciprocal of pi with this formula equivalent to 1/math.pi

Comment: I don't understand the goal of the exercise. You cannot get a better precision of pi (than already available as `math.pi`) when using floating point numbers in your calculations.

Comment: Post text, not images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Thank you sorry, this was a scuffed post, I'll be sure to have better formats for posts as well.

Comment: You're aware that the calculation line is **not** inside the loop?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I think that image is ok. It's not like I'd want to copy any of its text. And the formula as text wouldn't look as good.

Comment: @KellyBundy Copying is only one aspect, there are close to a dozen reasons cited in the link I posted. For instance, an image isn't searchable. It's not like the title of the post is specific enough, but "infinite series approximation" would be, if it wasn't pictorial.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I know there are more reasons, but I think that's the usual most important one. It's also the first one mentioned there. The others seem less important or not applicable or even *wrong* in this case. Like I said, the formula as text wouldn't look as good, it would be *harder* to read. And note that that list is prefaced with: *"You should not post code (or error/exception messages, log files, configuration files, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image because"*. I'd say the formula isn't any of that, so the whole thing doesn't even apply

Comment: (Though the image should better only show the formula, the rest is just unnecessary distraction and makes the formula smaller.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea with the `for` loop is that you add up a part of the summation on each iteration. So you should keep track of the total sum so far and add to it each time. Because of math properties, you can multiply by the constant that’s outside the summation while summing so you don't need to at the end.

```
import math
N = 132
pi_approximate_inv = 0
for k in range(0, N+1):
    print("The N value is", k)
    pi_approximate_inv += (2*math.sqrt(2)/9801) * ((math.factorial(4*k) * (1103+26390*k))/((math.factorial(k)**4) * (396**(4*k))))
    print("The pi approximate is", 1.0/pi_approximate_inv)
```

You also missed some parentheses at `(396**(4*k))` which I added. Also, it should be `print("The N value is", k)` (`k` not `N`) because it is showing what the result would be if it stopped right there at `k`.

Because of floating point precision limits, it appears to max out at N=2 (meaning 3 iterations).

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful to see what I've been doing wrong. I'm such a noob with Python atm and I was looking at the equation knowing I messed something up and NEEDED different insight on it.